# is "newPageLoaded" flag? Is it DOM or Networked based?

Tags: selenium

Can anyone tell me by what means Selenium tests trigger the page load is complete ie "newPageLoaded" flag? Is it DOM based (i.e.document.ready()) or network based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newPageLoaded function is called from the selenium browserbot js file meaning it is DOM based and not network based